How to filter query Supabase table based on another junction table and return all values even if not part of the initial filter?
The title of the question could be improved, sorry about that. I have 3 tables: job, skill and job_skill (M:M junction table between job and skill).
I am trying to filter jobs based on a skill but I want to return all skills for a given job that was returned even if these skills were not selected as the filter.
For example: one job X has 5 skills A, B, C, D and E. In my filter, I have skill B. I want the job to be returned to include skill B, of course, but also all its other skills and not only B. Here is my simplified query below.
let skillsArray = [B]
let query = supabase.from('job').select(*,skill!inner(skill_name))

Then, I chain it with:
 query = query.in('skill.skill_name', skillsArray);

In the query results, I get job X with only skill B despite job X having also skills A, C, D and E. How can I modify my query such that these skills are also included?
In my console logs, I have these two situations highlighted in job results based on the filter skill 'spanish':
The job has only one skill displayed in results despite having multiple:
job: This is a test job  
skills: [
  { skill_name: 'spanish' },
]

Here is how I would expect the job to be displayed including its multiple skills:
job: This is a test job  
skills: [
  { skill_name: 'spanish' },
  { skill_name: 'api' },
  { skill_name: 'business_consulting' },
  { skill_name: 'mandarin' },
  { skill_name: 'microsoft_excel' }
]

